# Как найти запись в базе не учитывая секунды?

Tags: php, mysqli

В базе есть запись со значением datetime **2021-04-06 13:15:45**

И у меня есть переменная в которой записана такая дата: **2021-04-06 13:15:13**

Мне нужен запрос который найдет запись из базы по дате, учитывая все кроме секунд.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Лучше всего `between`  Там 13:15 и 13:15.99999.  Покольку between захватывает весь участок - можно неравенством x >= 13:15 and x < 13:16.    between и неравенство задейстует индексы. Преобразования скорее всего не будут задействовать индексы и поиск будет медленным.

Comment: SELECT MyTime - second(MyTime) as `MyTime' FROM MyTable;